# User registration email

Tags: magento2, email-templates, user, registration

How can I edit user registration email of Magento2 ? I need to know the location of the email template which is send after an User registration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find the new account email template at below path

> /your_magento/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/account_new.html

You can find other customer related email template in same folder